# cannot build apache thrift due to ruby rake errors

Tags: rake, thrift

I am trying to build thrift from source tarball (https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/thrift/0.9.0/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz), but it fails with this error:

```
Making all in rb
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/akonsu/a/thrift-0.9.0/lib/rb'
/usr/local/bin/rake 
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What also helps, if you are not interested in Ruby in the first place, is configure Thrift to do without.

```
$ ./configure --without-ruby
```

So that is `--without-ruby`, and NOT `--without-rb` as some other sources suggest.

and then run `make` and `sudo make install`.

It is a known bug apparently.
I found this here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1367

(I am on on Mac OS X 10.7.5, BTW. I don't know about any other versions/platforms...)

Answer (score 11):

this helped:

```
gem install rspec
```